# How to set up Apache to tell two domains apart?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am just starting to look at PHP and Apache servers (at the moment use Ruby on Rails). I am looking to get two simple index.php files rendering in the browser, but they will be two separate sites. I have installed everything I need to I believe.

So if I go to `localhost` I get the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. This might be such a simple question but where do I store my files and directories? I have been looking in `/var/www/`.

I would like to create 2 sample sites as previously said. Could anyone point out where I should be looking and how I differentiate the two sites?

Comment: Just pop an `index.php` in that folder for something to work in your home page.

Answer (score 1):

`/var/www/` is your root folder for apache so your localhost is pointing to www. To create 2 different website you will require to create 2 new folder in `www` folder e.g web1 and web2 then `localhost/web1` will point to `/var/www/web1` same will goest for web2.

You can also set virtual host to make your web url like `web1.com` and `web2.com` check here on how to set virtual host in ubnuntu https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to welcome you in this beautiful world of PHP :)

Now look into this file : `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and locate for this config `DocumentRoot "THIS_IS_YOUR_DOC_ROOT_RICHLEWIS"`.

You can change it to your favorite document root an d restart Apache, or simply put your files here(php, html, images...

Comment: That's how you change the path of a single site. The question is asking about hosting multiple sites.